# Calling PUT web api : Cross-Origin Request Blocking Issue

Tags: angular, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, cors

i'm trying to call a PUT web api implemented in ASP.NET, from an angular service i got `Cross-Origin Request Blocking: The "Same Origin" policy does not allow access to the remote resource located at http://localhost:8888/api/users/17. Reason: Missing method in the "Access-Control-Allow-Methods" header`

i was able to call GET and POST method from anglar without a problem

source code :

```
edit(user : User) : Observable<object> {
      his.httpClient.put('http://localhost:8888/api/users/' + user.userId, user);
}
```

here is PUT web api :

```
        [HttpPut("{id}")]
        public async Task<ActionResult> Put(int id, [FromBody] UserViewModel model)
        {    
            try
            {                    
                var user = _mapper.Map<UserViewModel, User>(model);
                var status = await _repository.UpdateUserAsync(user);
                if (!status)
                {
                    return BadRequest("failed to edit user");
                }
                return Ok(_mapper.Map<User, UserViewModel>(user));
            }
            catch (Exception exp)
            {
                _loger.LogError(exp.Message);
                return BadRequest("failed to edit user");
            }
        }
```

and i've also added Cors in services in startup class as follows :

```
        services.AddCors(options =>
        {
            options.AddPolicy("CorsPolicy",
                builder => builder.AllowAnyOrigin()
                .AllowAnyMethod()
                .AllowAnyHeader()
                .AllowCredentials());
        });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've forgot to add your policy to each request:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
{
    app.UseCors("CorsPolicy");

    // ...
}
```

If you want to add policy only to desired controllers and actions, then you dont't need to write the above code, however apply this attribute actions or controllers:

```
[EnableCors("CorsPolicy")]
```

Comment: i've added app.UseCors("CorsPolicy"); and it works, actually i was using app.UseCors(builder => builder.WithOrigins("http://localhost:4200").AllowAnyHeader()) that i found on internet